# How to autowired bean of spring class

Tags: java, spring

I can have create bean with explicit bean factory method.

```
package org.package;

import org.springframework.security.web.PortResolver;
import org.springframework.security.web.PortResolverImpl;


@Configuration
public Configuration {

    @Bean
        public PortResolver portResolver(){
            return new PortResolverImpl();
        }

}
```

My goal is avoid factory method.

Comment: Annotate the `PortResolveImpl` class with `@Component` and make your `@Configuration` `@ComponentScan` its package.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis You should post that as an answer.

Comment: As you noticed this class form spring library. I am not sure about @Component. Could you explain it?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a factory method, let Spring instantiate an instance of your class for you by annotating your class with `@Component` and make your `@Configuration` class `@ComponentScan` its package.

When Spring scans that package, it will find your class, use its default constructor (or constructor annotated with `@Inject` or `@Autowired`) and use it to make an instance of your class. Spring will then add that instance to its context.

Because `PortResolveImpl` is not under your control, you will need to use a `@Bean` factory method.

Comment: As you pointed it is not custom class this class from Spring lib and is not made as component.

Comment: @user1459144 There is no work around for that. You will have a `@Bean` factory method or some other process (listener) to add it to your context. Can't do it automatically without `@Component`